# How to transfer header and body to thidrd processor in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, http, apache-camel

I'm setting some headers + body in Processor() then it it send to "www.test.com", next in SecondProcessor() i recive response from this site. Is it possible to receive in SecondProcessor a pair of headers + body from Procesor() and response from the site ? Now i'm using cache for this, but is there a "Apache Camel" way to to this ? Pseudo code below.

```
from("direct:test").process(new Processor()).to("www.test.com").process(new SecondProcessor());
```

Answer (score 0):

The Camel way for this would be to use the [Aggregator EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/aggregate-eip.html) or the [Content Enricher EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/content-enricher.html) to aggregate both the current message body and the new response body.

However, the "cheap" way of doing this is to backup the message body in an Exchange property before you call "www.test.com"

```
.setProperty("bodyBackup", body())
```

And later you can restore it from the property

```
.setBody(exchangeProperty("bodyBackup"))
```